# Changing tooltip for link buttons

Tags: tinymce-4

Does anyone know how to change the tooltip for the TinyMCE 4.x link buttons:

[image: link button tooltip]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tooltips are defined when the button is created.  For the button in question look in the link plugin code which is in the `plugins/link` folder within TinyMCE.  You can find the `addButton` code there and change it as needed:

```
editor.addButton('unlink', {
    icon: 'unlink',
    tooltip: 'Remove link',
    cmd: 'unlink',
    stateSelector: 'a[href]'
});
```

....note that there are both minified and non-minified versions of the plugin code so change both to make sure your changes will work regardless of whether or not you load the minified or non-minified version of TinyMCE.